# WSO2 API Manager(wso2am-4.1.0) - Cannot Login to Publisher and Devportal After Changing the Default Hostname

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using wso2am-4.1.0 and I changed the default hostname and defined a proxy port. Further, I fronted the APIM using an Nginx.
However, once I try to login to the publisher or access the devportal, it fails due to authenticationendpoint being not found (probably the redirection to a certain endpoint fails).

**deployment.toml**

```
hostname = "<mydomain>"
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
server_role = "default"

[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443
```

**Error in the browser network console**

[image: /authenticationendpoint 404 Not Found]

Any viable solution for this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Update:

**Nginx Configuration**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <MY_DOMAIN>;
    return 301 https://<MY_DOMAIN>$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/<MY_CER>.cer;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/<MY_KEY>.key;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/<CONF>.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/<CONF>.error.log debug;
  server_name <MY_DOMAIN>;

  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload";
  add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'" always;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
  add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'origin';
  #add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';" always;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 location / {
   return 301 https://<MY_DOMAIN>/authenticationendpoint/;
 }
  location /authenticationendpoint {
                limit_except GET HEAD POST { deny all; }
                proxy_pass https://xx.x.x.x:9443;
                proxy_set_header x-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                }


  location /logincontext {
                limit_except GET HEAD POST { deny all; }
                proxy_pass https://xx.x.x.x:9443;
                proxy_set_header x-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                }

  location /oidc {
                limit_except GET HEAD POST { deny all; }
                proxy_pass https://xx.x.x.x:9443;
                proxy_set_header x-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                }


  location /oauth2 {
                limit_except GET HEAD POST { deny all; }
                proxy_pass https://xx.x.x.x:9443;
                proxy_set_header x-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                }

  location /commonauth {
                limit_except GET HEAD POST { deny all; }
                proxy_pass https://xx.x.x.x:9443;
                proxy_set_header x-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                }

  location /publisher {
                limit_except GET HEAD POST PUT { deny all; }
                proxy_pass https://xx.x.x.x:9443;
                proxy_set_header x-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                }

  location /devportal {
                limit_except GET HEAD POST PUT { deny all; }
                proxy_pass https://xx.x.x.x:9443;
                proxy_set_header x-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                }

}
```

Comment: Did you find this request in http_access logs of APIM? It will help to identify whether the request has reached APIM or the issue is with proxy configurations

Comment: Yes. The request reaches the APIM and it is visible in the http_access log

Comment: Are you exposing 8243 port of gateway via 443 (Nginx) ?

Comment: No. I'm exposing the management port, 9443 using Nginx.

Comment: @LilanMihiranga please share your NginX configurations. Do you get a response body with the 404? Also, did you run any APIM profile optimization scripts?

Comment: @ycr updated the question with the Nginx configuration. I'm getting an html page with Error 404 - Not Found. No, I did not run any APIM profile optimization scripts.

Answer (score 1):

From your config, I can't exactly tell what's going on. But your 404 is being generated from the `authenticationendpoint` it seems. For example, if you try to call the `authenticationendpoint` with an invalid path you will see a 404.

```
curl https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint  => 302

curl https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/xxx  => 404
```

So I suspect given you have a default `localtion` block(`location /`) in your NginX to redirect to `authenticationendpoint` in your request flow something is redirected to the default block. Hence you are getting the 404. I would suggest checking this in the Network traces in the browser console.

Also, another important thing you have missed is, you have to add a location block to capture requests to `/api` as well.